# Issue in using cookie in angular js

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I'm trying to use cookies ( set and retrieve), I have this code copies from a site and changed it, but I wouldn't work and all my angular parts stop working.
This is a sample of angular website
can you tell me where the problem is?

```
var app = angular.module('test', ['ui.bootstrap'], ['ngCookies']);
app.controller('ExampleController', ['$cookieStore', function ($scope, $cookieStore) {
    // Put cookie
    $cookieStore.put('myFavorite', 'oatmeal');
    // Get cookie
    $scope.itemValue = $cookieStore.get('myFavorite');
    // Removing a cookie
    //$cookieStore.remove('myFavorite');
}]);
```

and usage is :

```
<span ng-controller="ExampleController">{{itemValue}}</span>
```

it gives me this error

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/$injector/modulerr?......

Comment: it show any error messages

Comment: yes: ReferenceError: $scope is not defined ; Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/$ .....................................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring your module wrong, the second parameter should be an array of dependencies, but you're passing each dependency as it's own separate array. It should be:

```
var app = angular.module('test', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngCookies']);
```

You're using a "minification safe" array for your controller, but you're only including `$cookieStore`, not `$scope`, it should be:

```
app.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$cookieStore', function ($scope, $cookieStore) {
    ...
}]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your syntax is incorrect, go through the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) to find the correct syntax for angular.